# What galvo scanner does your SLS 3D printer use? Normally which ones should I prefer while buying one

Tags: print-quality, laser, sls, slm, printing-powder

I wanna buy an SLS 3D printer and I figured it uses Galvo scanners to sinter powder. The whole printing operation depends on this Galvo scanner thing. What Galvo Scanner does your printer use and what are the specs? I am talking f_theta and speed. I would greatly appreciate you taking a minute to answer this.

Comment: Have you checked with the manufacturer of the printer to see which scanners it uses?

Comment: They told me but I wanted to know what normally people use.